# WSO2 - Identity Server - MySQL NDB cluster compatibility

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-identity-server

In the latest version of WSO2 products, we found that ISKM 7.0 is compatible with mysql NDB cluster whereas MI 4.3 is using INNODB cluster. We would like to know if NDB will still applicable for MI or not and what type of mysql cluster will be used in the future releases.