# WSO2 - Identity Server - MySQL clustering support

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Does WSO2 identity server support Mysql clustering?

If yes, what steps and scripts are needed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WSO2 - Identity Server - MySQL NDB cluster compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77879200/wso2-identity-server-mysql-ndb-cluster-compatibility)

Comment: the mentioned question is not answered

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Identity Server does support MySQL clustering.

Check - https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/set-up-separate-databases-for-clustering/

WSO2 IS is shipped with scripts for creating the required tables in all the required databases: The scripts for creating tables for user management and registry data are stored in the <IS_HOME>/dbscripts folder.

You can use clustering scripts from it.
eg: mysql_cluster.sql

Comment: Thank you for your help. Ill check the link. I am using version 5.7. I executed the following scripts: /dbscripts/mysql_cluster5.7.sql ran perfectly but /dbscripts/apimgt/mysql_cluster5.7.sql   is returning errors (for example saying that cascade is a limitation in ndb clustering). Should i skip this script?